# Why isn't my form working?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I currently have a button that when clicked it will show to 2 form links. When you click on one of the form links a different form should show. But for some reason I can't get the second form to show; when I click on the second form link it either closes the first form or opens the first form.

Why isn't my form working?.Here is the sample code.

```js
 $("#formButton1").click(function () {
      $("#form1").toggle();
      $("#form2").toggle();
 });
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="formButton1" style="background-color:#EEEEEE; border-color:darkgrey; color:black;"></button>
 <form id="form1" method="post" style="display:none;">
      <div class="card">
           <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                     <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="font-size:15px;">
                          Vault Status
                     </a>
                </h5>
           </div>
           <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="card-block">
                     <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <p>  This script returns status of vault servers for the chosen environment. It is used to determine if any servers overlap in order to detect a split brain.</p>
                          </div>
                          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select Environment</label>
                          <select multiple class="form-control" id="test1">
                               <option>RTP Prod</option>
                               <option>OMA Prod</option>
                               <option>BGI</option>
                               <option>BG2</option>
                               <option>Cloud</option>
                               <option>Workstation</option>
                               <option>QA</option>
                               <option></option>
                          </select><br />
                          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </form>

 <form id="form2" method="post" style="display:none;">
      <div class="card">
           <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                     <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="font-size:15px;">
                          Form 2
                     </a>
                </h5>
           </div>
           <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
           <div class="card-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <p>  This script returns status of vault servers for the chosen environment. It is used to determine if any servers overlap in order to detect a split brain.</p>
                     </div>
                     <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select Environment</label>
                     <select multiple class="form-control" id="test2">
                          <option>Test</option>
                          <option>OMA Prod</option>
                          <option>BGI</option>
                          <option>BG2</option>
                          <option>Cloud</option>
                          <option>Workstation</option>
                          <option>QA</option>
                          <option></option>
                     </select><br />
                     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: submit buttons submit.... so you are submitting the form onclick, submitting the form sends the page to the server, the browser reloads.

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you click on "Vault Status" which form must be show?

Comment: When I click on vault status form 1 should show, form 2 should show when form 2 is clicked

Comment: Change the button to be `type="button"` not submit.... I am too lazy to find a dupe

Comment: Do you have any other code other than this, you seem to trying to make it like an accordion ?

Comment: @JismonThomas I have other code but It is kind of irrelevant to this particular portion. This is the only portion not working.

Comment: Check if you miss a reference for bootstrap library in your code

Comment: @epascarello I tried changing the button and still received the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss a reference to Bootstrap library in your code. Make sure that you include it for both bootstap css and javascript:

You need to change the id of the div for form1 I renamed it to collapseOne

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```js
$("#formButton1").click(function () {
      $("#form1").toggle();
      $("#form2").toggle();

    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="formButton1" 
        style="background-color:#EEEEEE; border-color:darkgrey; color:black;"> 
        </button>
            
            
            <form id="form1" method="post" style="display:none;">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" style="font-size:15px;">
                                Vault Status
                            </a>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <p>  This script returns status of vault servers for the chosen environment. It is used to determine if any servers overlap in order to detect a split brain.</p>
                                </div>
                                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select Environment</label>
                                <select multiple class="form-control" id="test1">
                                    <option>RTP Prod</option>
                                    <option>OMA Prod</option>
                                    <option>BGI</option>
                                    <option>BG2</option>
                                    <option>Cloud</option>
                                    <option>Workstation</option>
                                    <option>QA</option>
                                    <option></option>
                                </select><br />
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <form id="form2" method="post" style="display:none;">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" style="font-size:15px;">
                                Form 2
                            </a>
                        </h5>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <p>  This script returns status of vault servers for the chosen environment. It is used to determine if any servers overlap in order to detect a split brain.</p>
                                </div>
                                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect2">Select Environment</label>
                                <select multiple class="form-control" id="test2">
                                    <option>Test</option>
                                    <option>OMA Prod</option>
                                    <option>BGI</option>
                                    <option>BG2</option>
                                    <option>Cloud</option>
                                    <option>Workstation</option>
                                    <option>QA</option>
                                    <option></option>
                                </select><br />
                                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: It's still displaying the Vault Status form when form 2 is clicked. Form 2 has a different first option value than Vault Status